# ScrollView not working in layout with android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Tags: android, xamarin

`ScrollView` not working in layout with `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`

In the code that you see, everything is correct if the `Toolbar` is removed. If the `Toolbar` is added, the button and content will not be displayed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/myToolBarRed"
    android:layout_margin="2dp" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <!-- Content here -->
            <Button
                android:text="Button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/button1" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss the `orientation` of the `LinearLayout`. The default value is `horizontal` so the second view is off-screen to the right. Lint check would show a warning if you miss orientation property in any `LinearLayout`

Add this to your root `LinearLayout`

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```